# Bullseye distribution (Rayleigh distr)

Tags: probability-distributions

Does anyone know what bullseye distribution is?

It should be a special case of Weibull distribution, but I haven't found any useful information after googled it.

Just for information, I heard this term from a german.

So it could be some uncommon translation from german to english.

And moreover, it represents a result due to a combination of independent impacts.

Thanks a lot. I would say this is a proper math question though no formulae are involved.

UPDATE:
Thanks Ross Millikan for the answer!

I have some following questions.

Does Rayleigh distribtuion only represent a 2D Gaussian distribution?

For completeness, this statement can be made as following:

$X \sim N(\mu, \sigma)$ and $Y \sim N(\mu, \sigma)$

then $\sqrt{X^{2}+Y^{2}} \sim Rayleigh(\sigma)$

So, is there a distribution which can be explicitly written for multidimensional Gaussian distribtuion,lets say N-dim?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chi-square_distribution#Definition

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One guess would be the [Rayleigh distribution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rayleigh_distribution), a two dimensional Gaussian.  Because there is zero area at the origin, the distribution in radius has a maximum.

Added: yes, you can do N dimensional Gaussian distributions.  If you look at the Rayleigh distribution, it is just a joint Gaussian in $x$ and $y$.  The distribution in $r=\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$ comes from integrating the area of an annulus from $r$ to $r+dr$.  You can do the same in more dimensions. multiplying Gaussians in $x, y, z, \ldots$.  The factor $r$ will become $r^{N-1}$ and the constant will change.

Comment: I agree with this guess.

Comment: hmm...that's my initial guess as well. Thanks for the confirmation.

Comment: As I've learned, for higher dimensions (N>2), should it be $\chi^{2}$ with n degree of freedom distributed rather than Rayleigh?

Comment: @newbie:  yes, the Rayleigh is the special case of $N=2$

Comment: @RossMillikan hmm, the ways to work things out are quite different between in academy and industry. they commonly don't ask why in industry. :S I'm gonna accept your answer. Thank you.

Comment: @RossMillikan  A minor quibble.  Newbie is not quite correct in his assertion about $\chi^2$ random variables.  With 2 variables, $\sqrt{X_1^2 + X_2^2}$ is a Rayleigh random variable but it is $X_1^2 + X_2^2$ that is a $\chi^2$ random variable with $2$ degrees of freedom (a.k.a. exponential random variable), and similarly for larger $n$, the pdf of the $\sqrt{\sum_i X_i^2}$ is proportional to $x^{n-1}\exp(-x^2/2)$ which is not a $\chi^2$ distribution.